# Constructing a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given two distinct, positive real numbers, how can I use these two numbers (and their non-zero integer linear combinations) to construct a sequence converges to zero? The sequence can only be of the two original positive numbers, or their non-zero integer linear combinations.

Comment: ..mmmm... if $a$ and $b$ are your numbers, then let $x_n = 0 \cdot a + 0 \cdot b$ for every $n$..?

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the comment. I've edited my question.

Comment: hint: think about euclidean algorithm and adapt accordingly (tho you need to specify what operations you can do, like if you are allowed to compare numbers)

Comment: @mm-aops Yes I have thought of the Euclidean Algorithm. It's extremely intuitive to me, but somehow when I try to pen it down, it's very difficult.

Comment: Okay, maybe it's not so difficult after all. I shall try to type it down in this post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume $0\lt x=x_0\le y=y_0$ are the two real numbers.  Define

$$x_{n+1}=\min(x_n,y_n-x_n)\quad\text{and}\quad y_{n+1}=\max(x_n,y_n-x_n)$$

The $x_n$'s (for $n\gt0$) is a sequence of nonzero integer linear combinations of $x_0$ and $y_0$.  It's not hard to show that it converges to $0$:  the inequalities

$$0\le x_{n+1}\le x_n\le y_n\le y_{n-1}$$

imply that each sequence, being non-negative and non-increasing, has a limit, say $x_n\to L$ and $y_n\to M$, with $0\le L\le M$, at which point $M=\max(L,M-L)$ implies $L=0$.

Remark (added later):  This construction can be thought of as the euclidean algorithm run in excruciating slow motion -- you gain simplicity of description at the expense of speed of convergence.

Comment: Why is $y_n \leq y_{n-1}$?

Comment: @ireallydonknow, if you accept that $0\le x_n\le y_n$, then $y_{n+1}=\max(x_n,y_n-x_n)\le\max(y_n,y_n)=y_n$, after which you can shift the index from $n$ to $n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question, and thought the asker was just trying to show the sequence exists. Still, I'll leave the answer here since it is not totally trivial to show.

---

Call the two numbers $a$ and $b$. Let $c = \inf\{r: r > 0, r = ka + lb$ for some integers $k$ and $l\}$. It suffices to show that $c = 0$. Suppose $c$ were not zero; we will arrive at a contradiction.

If there were distinct $k_n a + l_n b$ decreasing to $c$, then $(k_{n+1} - k_n)a + (l_{n+1} - l_n)b$ would decrease to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, implying $c = 0$, a contradiction. So we can assume there are not distinct $k_n a + l_n b$ decreasing to $c$. In other words there are some $k$ and $l$ such that $ka + lb = c$.

Next, observe that if there were $k'$ and $l'$ such that $k'a + l'b$ were not an integer multiple of $c$, then $mc < k'a + l'b < (m+1)c$ for some integer $m$, so that $0 < (k' - mk)a + (l' - ml)b < c$, contradicting minimality of $c$.

So all $k'a + l'b$ are integer multiples of $c$. In particular $a$ and $b$ are integer multiples of $c$, meaning $a$ and $b$ are rational multiples of each other. Writing $a = {m \over n} b$ for integers $m$ and $n$ then $na - mb = 0$. This implies $c =0$, a contradiction and we are done.

Comment: But does this *construct* the sequence ?

Comment: No, this just shows there is such a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

ok, suppose we can use the floor function and we can compare numbers. what we do is pretty much the euclidean algorithm. let's start with $a > b$ and let $x_1 := a$, $x_2 := b$. assume $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are already defined and the sequence is strictly decreasing and positive. if at any point we get $x_n = 0$ we stop (that's the case if $a$ and $b$ are proportional), so lets assume this doesn't happen. let now
$$x_{n+1} := x_{n-1} - [\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}]x_n$$
$x_{n+1}$ is an integer combination of $a$ and $b$ if all the $x_n$'s are. moreover $x_{n+1} < x_n$ because 
$$x_{n+1} - x_n = x_{n-1} - ([\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}] + 1 )x_n  < 0$$ since $([\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}] + 1 )> \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$. this is a decreasing and bounded sequence hence it has a limit point $g$. if it's $0$ then we're done, so let's assume $g>0$. the floor function is right-continuous  (continuous from the right, i.e. it's continuous at $y$ when considered on an interval $[y, y+\epsilon)$. since our sequence is decreasing that's all we need - we can plug $g$ into the recurence definition which gives
$$g = g - [\frac{g}{g}]g = 0$$ and so we're done.

edit:
oh, to see that the combinations are never $0$ observe that if $a$ and $b$ are not proportional over $\mathbb{Q}$ (the only case we need to consider) this can never happen since if $x_{n-1}$ and $x_n$ are integer combinations of $a$ and $b$ and $x_{n+1} = 0$ then this means $[ \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}] = \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$ so $\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n} \in \mathbb{Z}$. let $x_{n-1} = ka + mb$, $x_n = ja + nb$, then $ka + mb = l(ja + nb)$ where all $k, m, j, n, l$ are integers. this means $a$ and $b$ are proportional over $\mathbb{Q}$, so we're done